# Java HashSet Points

Tags: java, хеширование, java-hashmap, hashset

Всем привет. Такой вопрос связанный по Jav'е, я ее пока еще изучаю. В общем есть задача и условие такое: **Найти такую точку заданного на плоскости множества точек, сумма расстояний от которой до остальных минимальна** я понимаю как ее решить математически используя эту формулу `Lmin = Σ(с верху n, а с низу i=1) √((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`, но у меня проблема заключается в том, что я использую HashSet после я ее конвертирую в HashMap а от туда у меня получается достать только значения `y` значения по `x` вообще не видит, я наверное не совсем правильный делаю подход к решении задачи буду рад помощи или совету как лучше достать данные из HashSet'а и потом уже по циклу найти минимум.

Вот мой код(если что класс Point - это готовый класс из пакета `import java.awt.Point;` так же я делал создавая собственный класс Point но проблема та же с HashMap y видит а x нет):

```
    Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>();
    points.add(new Point(9, 0));
    points.add(new Point(1, 1));
    points.add(new Point(5, 6));
    points.add(new Point(3, 3));
    points.add(new Point(2, 7));
    points.add(new Point(1, 8));
    points.add(new Point(6, 1));
    System.out.println(points);

    Map<Double, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(Point ob : points) {
        map.put(ob.getX(), ob.getY());
    }
    System.out.println(map);

    double sum_m = 0;
    for(double f : map.values()) {
        sum_m+=f;
    }
    System.out.println(sum_m);
```

Comment: Почитайте про `Map`. Вы используете `x` в качестве ключа, это неправильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` не самая подходящая структура для решения такой задачи, как минимум потому что принципиально не хранит повторяющиеся ключи. Вы не сможете положить в него несколько точек с одинаковой координатой `X`. Из точек (1,1) и (1,8) останется только одна, пр чем трудно предсказать какая. Да и зачем?

Для каждой точки переберите в цикле весь `Set` и вычислите суммарное расстояние. Запомните точку с минимальной суммой.